# How to listen to media keys in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, io, keyboard, media-player

I'm looking to make a little media program in node, but I've not yet found how to capture/listen for [keyboard media keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard#Miscellaneous).

I've checked a few libraries (such as: [keypress](https://npmjs.org/package/keypress) and [KeyboardJS](https://npmjs.org/package/KeyboardJS)) on http://npmjs.org and have pretty much come up dry (many were browser only libraries).

Any ideas?

Thanks girls and guys!

Comment: OS? (unless you want to go very low level using something like https://github.com/hanshuebner/node-hid )

Comment: Windows and Ubuntu primarily; but I might still look into the node-hid Lib you posted. Cheers!

Comment: under X11 my special keys are reported - check out https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11

Comment: Thanks for the link! Got any examples of how to get said key reports?

Comment: It's easy to listen keycodes when you have window with a focus. Add keypress event mask if you are creating window or modify existing window attributes to have event mask. See https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11/blob/master/examples/smoketest/getkeyboardmapping.js example. To intercept keys for all windows you need to grab keyboard (no exemple yet, sorry)